# How to view traffic over a forwarded ssh port?

Tags: ssh

It is possible to setup an SSH port forward where the ssh client prints out the traffic exchanged over the ssh port to the screen or a file.

I am trying to debug a problem and want to see what is being sent between a java process running on my local machine and a remote process running on Solaris. I am using the port forwarding via ssh so that i can step through the java program. Normally I would have to copy 
the .java files to the Solaris machine, build them and run and it is not very productive way to debug, thus the port forwarding. The client and server as using IIOP protocol so  I can't use an http proxy to monitor the traffic.

Comment: Might just be easier to use e.g., wireshark or tcpdump to listen to the traffic. You should be able to capture it on the host-local interface (`lo` on Linux, not sure what Solaris calls it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would cheat and put a couple of `netcat`'s and a `tee` in the pipeline:

```
nc -k -l -p $localport -c "tee file.out | nc 127.0.0.1 $portforwardport"
```

where `$localport` is an arbitrary port to point your java process at and `$portforwardport` is your ssh port forward port number.  The `-k` makes the listening netcat stay listening rather than exiting after the first time a client disconnects. The output will end up in `file.out` on your localhost.

Comment: `nc` (netcat) did not take the `-c` option but `ncat` did it for me.

Answer (score 3):

As @derobert said in the comments your best bet is likely going to be with a tool such as wireshark. You'll want to target the traffic coming in and out of your Java process prior to getting into the ssh tunnel. Since the tunnel is encrypted you're not going to be able to peak inside it.

Also the sectools.org website maintains an extensive list of sniffing tools which you can check out if wireshark doesn't seem to fit your needs.

- http://sectools.org/tag/sniffers/

Answer (score 0):

You may use `tcpdump`

```
$> sudo tcpdump -vv -x -X -s 1500 -i lo 'port 8000'
```

This works if you have mapped the ssh tunnel to localhost (interface `lo`) to port `8000`

```
-vv verbose level 2
-X  print data in hex and ASCII 
-x  print data in hex to a max limit of -s 
-s  snaplen - limit of data to print
-i eth0 tcpdump on the eth0 interface
```

You may allso save this script in your path as `sniff-port`

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
# use the first argument as port. if not defined default to 8080
PORT=${1:-8080} 
# sniff sniff
sudo tcpdump -vv -x -X -s 1500 "port $PORT" -i lo
```

and then use it as

```
$> sniff-port 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ tcpdump -i <network-interface> port <port-number>
```

To view network interface

```
$ ifconfig
```

Just specify network interface and port number
This will show the following details:

Source IP Address
Destination IP Address
Protocol
Length
Info related to SYN, SYN-ACK, PSH-ACK, etc.

Answer (score -2):

You can use kismet https://kismetwireless.net/ for sniffing.

Comment: Kismet is for wireless sniffing